# Unable to use Elasticsearch new multi_terms aggregation via Java High Level Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I`ve updated my ES cluster to the version 7.12 to use brand new [multi-terms aggregations](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/67597). I want to do something like this:

```
AggregationBuilders.multiTerms(field)
```

in my Java Rest Client (from
*org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client*)

But as I see, there is no builder for multi terms. I`ve found it in [sources on GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/7.12/x-pack/plugin/analytics/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/xpack/analytics/multiterms/MultiTermsAggregationBuilder.java). As I understood, this class is externalized into some **x-pack** plugin and I can't get access to it. Should I add this plugin to my classpath? And where can I find it?

Thank you

Comment: same here! looking for supported